# Как закрасить разделители в UIStackView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Здравствуйте! У меня есть горизонтальный StackView, в него вложены еще несколько StackView, и задан разделитель(отступ(spacing)) между ними.

Вопрос, можно ли как нибудь закрасить эти разделители? Пробовал задать бэкграунд главному StackView, но ничего не вышло, разделители не покрасились, похоже разделители рисуются выше по уровню чем бэкграунд. Вставлять промежуточные вьюшки с нужным цветом тоже не вариант, т.к. у StackView задан режим equal fill.

Comment: Spacing это расстояние между элементами, вы его хотите покрасить?

Comment: да, его. Хочу сделать цветные разделители

Comment: то есть вы хотите добавить новый объект к коллекции, который будет служить разделителем?

Comment: хотелось бы обойтись без добавления новых вьюшек как разделителей, а закрасить именно отступы которые появляются при задании spacing в UIStackView. Вот пример, http://s020.radikal.ru/i709/1511/11/08a514bf2f18.png вьюшки эти лежат на StackView и задан отступ в 1 поинт, вот как бы его закрасить. Бэкграунд менять уже пробовал, неработает.

Comment: почему бы не добавить по вью к каждму из вложенных UIStackView вместо разделителся

Comment: главный StackView горизонтальный, а вложенные вертикальные, в них никак не засунуть вьюшку сбоку. А в главный StackView тоже не засунуть между ними, т.к. свойство стоит "равномерное заполнение"

Comment: думаю может быть как то через layer можно задать? что-то типа border только с одной стороны

Comment: сделайте свой сабкласс `UIStackView` и в нем в `drawRect` добавляйте что вам надо

Comment: пробовал сделать сабкласс и в drawRect через контекст рисовать, но что-то не получилось, да и плюс потом даже если получится, нужно будет отслеживать переворот экранов и т.д. чтобы корректно перерисовывать. В итоге центральные вложенные StackView положил не сразу на StackView, а в вьюху, внутри вьюхи выставил констреины StackView с отступом в 1 пойнт. Задал вьюхе бэкграунд с цветом которым должны быть разделители, а лейблам внутри StackView задал белый бэкграунд, и получилось то что я хотел получить в итоге. http://s017.radikal.ru/i417/1511/c9/0b46c5b82f30.png

Comment: публикуйте ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Закрасить сами разделители(spacing) мне так и не удалось, ни установкой бэкграунда, ни через наследование UIStackView c последующим рисованием в контексте в методе drawRect, не получилось даже установить свойство layer.border на StackView

Поэтому с эмитировать разделители и покрасить их, в моём случае можно следующим способом:

1. Т.к. в ряду у меня всего 3 ячейки, мне достаточно "установить"
   разделители слева и справа у центральной ячейки.
2. Т.к. у меня StackView вложенные в StackView и изменения их бэкграунда не
   работает, нужно добавить дополнительный промежуточный слой в виде
   обычной View. Получится в итоге примерно такая иерархия StackView-> View-   >StackView->Label
3. Задаём констрейны StackView который лежит у нас во View, с такими отступами какой шириной вы хотите видеть разделители.
4. Задаём View цвет бэкграунда, такой каким вы хотите чтобы были разделители
5. Задаём например белый бэкграунд элементам лежащие последними в иерархии, чтобы выделить наши разделители, у меня например это Label'ы